# Can we detect selenium undetected chromedriver using JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, selenium, browser, selenium-chromedriver, fingerprinting

Use Case:
I've to write a script in JavaScript which will detect the selenium `undetected chromedriver` presence.

Comment: You want to build something that detects if somebody is running selenium scripts against your website?

Comment: Yes. only selenium is detectable as it adds some variables in the window object but `undetected_chromedriver` removes then. That's the challenge!

Answer (score 0):

You can try using [creep-js](https://abrahamjuliot.github.io/creepjs/)
[github](https://github.com/abrahamjuliot/creepjs)

In my case, it was able to detect undetected-chromedriver and [Selenium-Profiles](https://github.com/kaliiiiiiiiii/Selenium-Profiles)